# Getting Prefixed CSS Properties in Opera via JavaScript

Tags: jquery, css

I have written some jQuery that is working perfectly in WebKit browsers and Firefox. I am now testing in Opera and am having issues with getting the transition duration for an element. This is my code:

```
slideSpeed = $(".animate-in").css("-o-transition-duration");
console.log("Slide Speed", slideSpeed);
```

With the following CSS:

```
.animate-in{
    -o-transition-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

For some reason, Opera doesn't return "2.5s". Can anyone explain why please?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UGdUs/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug.

If you inspect element you can see that all computed style tor transitions are empty. Even if you try to directly acces the property from pure JavaScript:

```
var delay = document.getElementById('id').style.OTransitionDelay;
```

it returns empty string. However if you set it this way

```
document.getElementById('id').style.OTransitionDelay = '2.5s';
```

And then retrieve it this way, it works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot the empty values in the computed styles. Will report it as a bug.